# How to use media upload on theme option page?

Tags: themes, media-library, theme-options

I want implement upload logo to my theme option page. Currently I follow [this code](http://themeshaper.com/sample-theme-options/)

What I have done for now load a related jquery for the media upload

```
function load_only() {
    add_thickbox();
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-option', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/js/jquery.option.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox','jquery-ui-core','jquery-ui-tabs'), '1.0');
}
```

Question

How to implement the upload form using existing media upload?

```
<input id="theme_options_upload" type="text" name="theme_options_upload" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options['theme_options_upload'] ); ?>" />
<input type="button" name="just_button" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Upload'); ?>" />
```

I want to know

1. How to link the button to `media-upload.php`
2. After we upload image and click `Insert into Post` button on media-upload the image will place into field `name="theme_options_upload"`

Let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are most likely  to save the url of the image and not the whole image tag,
and there is a great tutorial that explains just how to use the media uploader in your own theme or plugin:
http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/

### update

In case of using this in a meta box you will need the post id so change the js code from:

```
jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});
```

to

```
jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
 post_id = jQuery('#post_ID').val();
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id='+post_id+'&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanks web design. There have a clue how to add `post_id=$post->ID`?

Comment: use global $post; and then $post->ID

Comment: `media-upload.php?post_id=ID&amptype=image&amp;TB_iframe=true` in wp 3.1 required `post_id=ID` if not we will getting Notice: Undefined index: post_id. If we put any ID the Insert into Post button will not shown. How to fix this one?

Comment: paste your code

Comment: hmmm.. exactly same like blog you post. if you read comments on the blog you will find same problem with me. most of them will asked how to make it work with post_id

Comment: i updated the answer

Comment: There is one odd thing about this code, and i've seen variations of the same example posted numerous times, is that this line.. `formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');` remains totally pointless, the var is defined but never used(so you can actually remove that line without ill effect).

Comment: In this case you are right but i have used it in different cases where i use multiple fields to overwrite the send to editor