# How to upload images using Settings API

Tags: theme-development, uploads, options

I want to allow users to upload images for use in a rotating banner. I tried using the media library, [but didn't get much help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18678/plugging-into-the-media-library-to-upload-images-not-associated-with-any-post) ... So I thought, I'd just implement the upload myself. But I encountered another problem... I am using the settings API they do the update options and stuff for me. How can I handle the upload then?

I thought of using the validate callback to upload images and then set $_POST variables manually so that Settings API can save those. But it sounds wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need a list of URL's selected from the Media Loader.  There are others out there, but I have a Theme Options Panel for your admin that is Settings API compliant.  It has an 'upload' option that uses the Media Loader to upload a file and fill a text field with the returned URL of that file. This is saved as an option with the Settings API. Perhaps you can get an idea from that. You could provide a pre-set amount of 'upload' options (5 URLS/images for example) or modify the code to handle it differently.

[Theme Options Panel Framework](http://diverge.blogdns.com/blog/wordpress-theme-options-panel-framework/)

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? I think in WP3 or 3.1 post_id is required? I am able to show the media library popup but selecting images does nothing

Comment: Version 3.1.3.  I just tested it again and it works fine with my Options Panel.  No post_id required because with the Media Loader, you wouldn't always be inserting into a post.  When you say it doesn't work, are you referring to your code or mine?

Comment: Ok I went to ur link b4. But I'll try it later or when I have time